# Avoiding for loop with numpy and function parameter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to get good at numpy and want to know if I can use values in exisiting arrays to serve as indices for a function that returns values for another array. I can do this:

```
def somefun(i):
    return i+1
x   = np.array([2, 4, 5])
k_labs = np.arange(100)
k_labs2 = k_labs[somefun(x[:])]
```

But how do I deal with using vectors in matrices in case x was a double array, where I just want to use one vector at a time as indices-arguments for a function, such as `X[:, i]`, without using for-loops?
such as would be the case in:

```
x   = np.array([[2, 4, 5],[7, 8, 9]])
def somefun(i):
    return i+1
k_labs = np.arange(100)
k_labs2 = k_labs[somefun(x[:, i])]
```

**EDIT ITERATION 2**
To get the gist of what I am trying to accomplish see the code below. In the function `pred` as you can see i wanted to write the things I've commented out in a numpy fashion that might work better yet. I have some probelms  though we the two lines I put in instead, since I get an error of wrong broadcast dimensions in the function called distance, at the the line where I try to assign the normalized vectors at a variable.

```
class kNN: 
  def __init__(self, X_train : np.array, label_train, val = None):
    self.X  = X_train#X[:-1, :]
    self.labels = label_train#X[-1, :]
    #self.k = k
    self.kNN_4all = None #np.zeros(self.X.shape[1])         
  
  def distance(self, x1):       
    x1 = np.tile(x1, (self.X.shape[1], 1)) #creates a matrix of len of X with copyes of x1 vector for easy matrix subtraction.
    dists = np.linalg.norm(x1 - self.X.T, axis = 1) #Flips to find linalg.norm for all the axis       
    return dists

  def k_nearest(self, x_vec, k):    
    k_nearest = self.distance(x_vec)
    k_nearest = np.argsort(k_nearest)[ :k]    
    kNN_labs = np.zeros(k_nearest.shape)
    kNN_labs[:] = self.labels[k_nearest[:]]
    unique, vote = np.unique(kNN_labs, return_counts=True)     
    return unique[np.argmax(vote)]

  def pred(self, X_test, k):      
    self.kNN_4all = np.zeros(X_test.shape[1])
    self.kNN_4all = self.k_nearest(X_test[:, :], k)
    #for i in range(X_test.shape[1]):      
     # NewLabel = self.k_nearest(X_test[:, i], k) #defines x_vec in matrix X  
     # self.kNN_4all[i] = NewLabel      
    #return self.kNN_4all
  
  def prec(self, labels_val):    
    elem_equal = (self.kNN_4all == labels_val).astype(int).flatten()    
    prec = np.sum(elem_equal)/elem_equal.shape    
    return 1 - prec[0]



X_train = X[:, :100]
labs_train = labs[:100]


pilot = kNN(X_train, labs_train)
pilot.pred(X[:,100:200], 10)
pilot.prec(labs[100:200])
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (78400,100) (100,784)
```

As we can see from the code the `k_nearest(self, x_vec, k)` takes one 1D-subarray, so passing any full matrix X will cause the broad-casting error, since the functions within k_nearest relies on passing only a 1D subarray.

I don't know if it really is possible to avoid for loops in this regard and use numpy to increment through 1D subarrays as arguments for a function, such that each call of the function with the arguments can be assigned to a different cell in another array, in this case the `self.kNN_4all`

Comment: For most transformation of the input matrix x to `some_fun` such as linear transformations of the sort in your sample function, you can write `k_labs[somefun(x[:])]` and get back a 2d array consisting elements retrieved from your 1d array using the 2d array of indices. That so long as there are no out of bound indices in the 2d array of indices.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I am looking for a way to retrieve from x just one of the two sub-arrays that should serve as a 1D array for the function, such that it might return n number of values where n refers to the length of the 1D array that was retrieved. If I just give write x[:] for a 2D-matrix as an argument of the function it wont work to serve as indices for the k_labs-array taht I defined.

Comment: Likewise you can't use the `X[:, :]` appraoch because that approach will mean that you will get the whole matrix X, whereas you are not interested in that, but only of the comprising vectors that you want to return one at a time.

Comment: Updated my message.

Comment: The error starts here(x1 - self.X.T), I didn't look further

Comment: That is correct. It is not erroneous though when you just stay with the for loop I first used. So perhaps if you want to do it without a for loop it would require the whole code to be rewritten.

Comment: You have several functions for which calculations are performed.
Probably because of this, it will not be possible to transfer all the data just like that.
Probably have to use a loop. As far as I understand, you want to make a nearest neighbor algorithm.
You can try to shorten the code using ready-made libraries, for example, Scikit-learn.
And read more about whimsical indexing. Example to access the values (specify the necessary indexes in square brackets separated by commas) arr[[1, 5, 7]]

Answer (score 0):

```
x = np.array([[2, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [33, 50, 71]])
x = x + 1

k_labs = np.arange(100)
ttt = k_labs[x]

print(ttt)
```

ttt creates an array that takes values from 'k_labs' based on pseudo-indexes 'x'. The array is accessed for example:

```
print(ttt[1])#[ 8  9 10]
```

If you want to refer to a certain value (for example, with indexes x[2]) alone, then the code will be as follows:

```
x = np.array([[2, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [33, 50, 71]])
x = x + 1

k_labs = np.arange(100)

print(k_labs[x[2]])
```

Comment: You are right about the 300, I just didn't see it. However your solution is still very static. The x[1, :] will indeed look at one of the 1D arrays in x, but what if we needed to go over all of the 1D arrays that need to be transformed by the function before being assigned to a new variable.

Comment: That is, you want to pass a two-dimensional array and get an array with values equal to the length of the passed array (indexes)? At the same time, without using a loop.

Comment: So what you suggested is almost what I am looking for. However as you can see from my code I want to find a numpy version of the for loop that would pass the 1D arrays of x to k_labs but without doing it with all of them at the same time, because then I would get broad casting problems wiht wrong dimensions. And this I want to do without using a for loop, if possible.

Comment: Besides the above comment, I have edited the question once more.